# Multiple keybinds to same command in Visual Studio (i.e. not vscode)

Tags: visual-studio

I am specifically using Visual Studio 2022 and would like to have two separate keyboard bindings to open the terminal (`View.Terminal`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer whilst writing this, just adding new keyboard shortcuts doesn't seem to remove the previous one(s) but this wasn't obvious throught the GUI. To change keyboard shortcuts one goes to `Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard` where one can see and set keyboard shortcuts. In my case it wasn't obvious because I had one keyboard shortcut per keyboard layout and the GUI only shows the keyboard shortcuts for one keyboard layout at a time.